# What is Mork's life span?

Tags: mork-and-mindy

Mork and Mindy was a comedic show in the 80s about an alien and a human living together while Mork observed our planet's culture. Mork was from the planet Ork. Though he looked human, his species evolved from the chicken instead of the ape and his people aged backwards. Mork looked like a man in his late twenties, maybe thirty. In the show there was an eight year old kid that was said to be eighty or ninety, so how old is Mork and how much longer does he have left to live?

Comment: na noo na noo!!

Comment: Another orkan, oh shaz bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the provenance of this site, but it lists many details about Mork, including a lifespan of 2000 years, at which time he needed to be "recharged". I do not know if that means that he is technically immortal or not.

[Tv Acres writeup on Mork](http://www.tvacres.com/aliens_mork.htm)

Answer (score 1):

As for how old he was it was not a biological function.  There was an episode where their downstairs neighbour stole the device used to control his age and kept twisting the dial and thus changing his age causing Mork to act in various ways.

I am not aware of the exact longevity of his species ever really being specified.